# How to write this query using JPA Criteria query?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Can anyone help me to get the JPA criteria query for the JPA query mentioned below.

```
SELECT p,l FROM Person p 
LEFT JOIN Language l ON (p.language = l.language and l.locale like :locale) 
AND p.name like :name 
AND p.time BETWEEN :startDate 
AND :endDate order by name asc
```

Comment: Can you show your implementations for Person and Language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that Person has a relation to Language here's what you would do in older Hibernate:

```
Criteria criteria = entityManager.createCriteria(Person.class);
Criteria languageCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("language");

languageCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("locale", locale));

criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", name));
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("time", startDate, endDate));

criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
```

and my first try at JPA 2.0:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createCriteria(Person.class);
Root<Person> pRoot = criteria.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Language> langJoin = criteria.join("language", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate conjunction = builder.conjunction();

criteria.where(builder.and(
    builder.like(langJoin.get(Language_.locale), locale),
    builder.like(pRoot.get(Person_.name), name),
    builder.between(pRoot.get(Person_.time), startDate, endDate));

criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(pRoot.get(Person_.name)));
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

*Edit:* Updated query to use only one `where` call.

Comment: Restrictions is not part of JPA specs, it's an Hibernate feature

Comment: Hey firstly thanks, I should have put this up in the question.
 There is **no relationship** b/w the entities person and language. Both person and language have a column in common (language(varchar)) on which I am joining. what is causing problem for me is that, I need to make a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** so that if there are no language data available for the person, still I should be able to get the person data with the language object as null.

Comment: Looking into it I think the edit I just did performs a left outer joint (JoinType.LEFT)

Comment: Hi, thanks the query looks fine, I just have one more silly issue, In the line 
criteria.where(builder.between(pRoot.get(Person_.time), startDate, endDate));

Actually the Person entity have a  @Embedded attribute  transaction, under which time comes. to give a clear picture, the line should look like
criteria.where(builder.between(pRoot.get(**Person_.Transaction_.time**), startDate, endDate));

How to do the text in bold?

Comment: You have to treat the embedded type as a joinl ike described here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html#criteria-join-singular.  This means yo need the following: Join<Person,Transaction> personTransaction = pRoot.join( Person_.transaction ); criteria.where(builder.between(personTransaction.get(Transaction_.time)));

Comment: By the way, it is customary to give the acceptable or correct answer a check mark, which gives the answerers an incentive to answer more of your questions.

Comment: @johncarl Thanks. My apologies for lately accepting the answer as usually i will be offline in weekend.

Comment: No, this is not yet complete, because "criteria.where(...)" can only issued once, since it would replace the criterias issued before. Better refer to pho312's solution below.

Comment: Shouldn't it be builder.createQuery(Person.class), instead of builder.createCriteria(Person.class)?

Answer (score 8):

Although the answer given by johncarl was accepted it doesn't look correct to me. The JavaDocs for CriteriaQuery.where() say:

> Modify the query to restrict the query result according to the
>   specified boolean expression. Replaces the previously added
>   restriction(s), if any.

As I understand it, each of the following lines (giving restrictions) will override the restrictions given previously:

```
criteria.where(builder.like(langJoin.get(Language_.locale), locale));
criteria.where(builder.like(pRoot.get(Person_.name), name));
criteria.where(builder.between(pRoot.get(Person_.time), startDate, endDate));
```

This means that in the end only the last restriction (between start and end date) would remain.

I threfore suggest following modifications to johncarl's answer:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createCriteria(Person.class);
Root<Person> pRoot = criteria.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Language> langJoin = criteria.join("language", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate[] restrictions = new Predicate[] { 
    builder.like(langJoin.get(Language_.locale), locale),
    builder.like(pRoot.get(Person_.name), name),
    builder.between(pRoot.get(Person_.time), startDate, endDate)
};

criteria.where(builder.and(restrictions));

criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(pRoot.get(Person_.name)));
```

However, this code looks really ugly! Please, feel free to edit if it's wrong and comment it if you see a better solution! I'd be gracefull!

Comment: Thank You indeed for your hint. criteria.where(...) cannot be used incrementally, since it replaces the criterias potentially passed before completely. on the other side,  a single issue of builder.and("array of where predicates") works. Great solution, pho312 :)

Comment: Thank you for a great hint! I totally loved your approach. I would simply add that one can make an ArrayList and simply add criteria as they come. One the other hand, I don't know why but pRoot.get(Person_.name) doesn't work for me. Anume I get an error with Person_ syntax.