# entitymanager.find() using foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

May we find an entity using entitymanager using the foreign key associated to it?

For example I have a class like this :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "shopping_bag")
    public class ShoppingBag {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
        private String id;

        @OneToOne
        private Member member;

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<Product> product = new HashSet<Product>();
}
```

Where Member is like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all Products knowing a Member id using entityManager!

A solution is to use Native SQL - or HSQL however I want to know if there is a more simple solution ... Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hibernate Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

```
List results = entityManager.createCriteria(ShoppingBag.class, "ShoppingBag")
    .createAlias("ShoppingBag.member", "member", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
    .add( Restrictions.eq("member.id", someStringValue) )
    .list();
```

[Rererence #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926363/how-to-write-this-query-using-jpa-criteria-query)
[Reference #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649754/select-entity-where-hibernate-onetoone-association-is-not-present)

Answer (score 1):

You clearly cannot use `find()` since that finds an object of a type with an id (as its javadoc tells you clear enough). 
You can do a `JPQL` query to get what you want.

```
SELECT p FROM ShoppingBag b JOIN b.product p JOIN b.member m WHERE m.id = :memberId
```